# Showing that a function is exponential by real analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\left( 0,\infty \right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a differentiable function strictly increasing. For every given $a\in\mathbb{R}$ the tangent line of $f$ at the point $(a,f(a))$ cuts the $x$ axis at the point $a-b$, where $b$ is a constant. Show that $f$ is an exponential function.

I can only get that $f(x)=bf'(x)$ for every $x\in(0,\infty)$.

One could think to resolve like in differential equations, but I need to use theorems from real analysis on derivatives.

I think I need to use that $f$ is strictly increasing, but I don't know how. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint: What’s $(\log(f))’$

Comment: from this i could get that $f\left( x\right) =e^{\dfrac{1}{b}\left( x-c\right) }$, but what I wonder now is why do they say that $f$ is increasing, I haven't used this fact.

Comment: I guess the equation should be $f'(x)=bf(x)$ instead. Also, $f$ strictly increasing means that $f'$ is always positive, which, by the differential equation, implies both $b$ and $f$ are always non-zero. This allows you to apply the hint above to the function $bf$.